# I want to trigger click function continuously using jquery or js

Tags: jquery, loops, click, auto

I am trying to trigger a function where each progress step triggers to next using jquery.I was able to autoclick the step process using setInterval function but, I am not able to repeat the functions. Please help me to achieve this would be appreciated. I am not a regular programmer. Was trying but unable to figure out how and where to use certain functons to trigger the desired result.

```js
 
    $(".step").click( function() {
    $(this).addClass("active").prevAll().addClass("active");
    $(this).nextAll().removeClass("active");    
});

$(".step01").click( function() {
    $("#line-progress").css("width", "3%");
    $(".discovery").addClass("active").siblings().removeClass("active");

});

$(".step02").click( function() {
    $("#line-progress").css("width", "25%");
    $(".strategy").addClass("active").siblings().removeClass("active");
});

$(".step03").click( function() {
    $("#line-progress").css("width", "50%");
    $(".creative").addClass("active").siblings().removeClass("active");
});

$(".step04").click( function() {
    $("#line-progress").css("width", "75%");
    $(".production").addClass("active").siblings().removeClass("active");
});

$(".step05").click( function() {
    $("#line-progress").css("width", "100%");
    $(".analysis").addClass("active").siblings().removeClass("active");
});

(function() {
    var inputs = document.getElementsByClassName('step'),
        current = 0,
        timer = window.setInterval(
            function () {
                var input = inputs[current];
                if (input) {
                    input.click();
                    current++;
                } else {
                    window.clearInterval(timer);
                }
            }
        ,3000);

}());
```

```css
.process-wrapper {
    margin:auto;
    max-width:1080px;
}

#progress-bar-container {
    position:relative;
    width:90%;
    margin:auto;
    height:100px;
    margin-top:65px;
}

#progress-bar-container ul {
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    padding-top:15px;
    z-index:9999;
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    margin-top:-40px
}

#progress-bar-container li:before {
    content:" ";
    display:block;
    margin:auto;
    width:30px;
    height:30px;
    border-radius:50%;
    border:solid 2px #aaa;
    transition:all ease 0.3s;
     
}

#progress-bar-container li.active:before, #progress-bar-container li:hover:before {
    border:solid 2px #fff;
         
    background: linear-gradient(to right, #E91E63 0%,#fff 100%); 
}

#progress-bar-container li {
    list-style:none;
    float:left;
    width:20%;
    text-align:center;
    color:#aaa;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    font-size:11px;
    cursor:pointer;
    font-weight:700;
    transition:all ease 0.2s;
    vertical-align:bottom;
    height:60px;
    position:relative;
}

#progress-bar-container li .step-inner {
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    bottom:0;
    font-size: 14px;
}

#progress-bar-container li.active, #progress-bar-container li:hover {
    color:#444;
}

#progress-bar-container li:after {
    content:" ";
    display:block;
    width:6px;
    height:6px;
    background:#777;
    margin:auto;
    border:solid 7px #fff;
    border-radius:50%;
    margin-top:40px;
    box-shadow:0 2px 13px -1px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    transition:all ease 0.2s;
     
}

#progress-bar-container li:hover:after {
    background:#555;
}

#progress-bar-container li.active:after {
    background:#207893;
}

#progress-bar-container #line {
    width:80%;
    margin:auto;
    background: #eee;
    height:6px;
    position:absolute;
    left:10%;
    top:57px;
    z-index:1;
    border-radius:50px;
    transition:all ease 0.9s;
}

#progress-bar-container #line-progress {
    content:" ";
    width:3%;
    height:100%;
    background: #207893;     
    background: linear-gradient(to right, #207893 0%,#2ea3b7 100%); 
    position:absolute;
    z-index:2;
    border-radius:50px;
    transition:all ease 0.9s;
}

#progress-content-section {
    width:90%;
    margin: auto;
    background: #f3f3f3;
    border-radius: 4px;
}

#progress-content-section .section-content {
    padding:30px 40px;
    text-align:center;
}

#progress-content-section .section-content h2 {
    font-size:17px;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    color:#333;
    letter-spacing:1px;
}

#progress-content-section .section-content p {
    font-size:16px;
    line-height:1.8em;
    color:#777;
}

#progress-content-section .section-content {
    display:none;
    animation: FadeInUp 700ms ease 1;
    animation-fill-mode:forwards;
    transform:translateY(15px);
    opacity:0;
}

#progress-content-section .section-content.active {
    display:block;
}

@keyframes FadeInUp {
    0% {
        transform:translateY(15px);
        opacity:0;
    }
    
    100% {
        transform:translateY(0px);
        opacity:1;
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="process-wrapper">
<div id="progress-bar-container">
    <ul>
        <li class="step step01 active"><div class="step-inner">HOME WORK</div></li>
        <li class="step step02"><div class="step-inner">RESPONSIVE PART</div></li>
        <li class="step step03"><div class="step-inner">Creative cREATIONS</div></li>
        <li class="step step04"><div class="step-inner">TESTIMONIALS PART</div></li>
        <li class="step step05"><div class="step-inner">OUR LOCATIONS</div></li>        
    </ul>
    <div id="line">
        <div id="line-progress"></div>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="progress-content-section">
    <div class="section-content discovery active">
        <h2>HOME SECTION</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec neque justo, consequat non fermentum ac, tempor eu turpis. Proin nulla eros, placerat non ipsum ut, dapibus ullamcorper ex. Nulla in dapibus lorem. Suspendisse vitae velit ac ante consequat placerat ut sed eros. Nullam porttitor mattis mi, id fringilla ex consequat eu. Praesent pulvinar tincidunt leo et condimentum. Maecenas volutpat turpis at felis egestas malesuada. Phasellus sem odio, venenatis at ex a, lacinia suscipit orci.</p>
    </div>
    
    <div class="section-content strategy">
        <h2>GALLERY SECTION</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec neque justo, consequat non fermentum ac, tempor eu turpis. Proin nulla eros, placerat non ipsum ut, dapibus ullamcorper ex. Nulla in dapibus lorem. Suspendisse vitae velit ac ante consequat placerat ut sed eros. Nullam porttitor mattis mi, id fringilla ex consequat eu. Praesent pulvinar tincidunt leo et condimentum. Maecenas volutpat turpis at felis egestas malesuada. Phasellus sem odio, venenatis at ex a, lacinia suscipit orci.</p>
    </div>
    
    <div class="section-content creative">
        <h2>Creative CREATIONS</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec neque justo, consequat non fermentum ac, tempor eu turpis. Proin nulla eros, placerat non ipsum ut, dapibus ullamcorper ex. Nulla in dapibus lorem. Suspendisse vitae velit ac ante consequat placerat ut sed eros. Nullam porttitor mattis mi, id fringilla ex consequat eu. Praesent pulvinar tincidunt leo et condimentum. Maecenas volutpat turpis at felis egestas malesuada. Phasellus sem odio, venenatis at ex a, lacinia suscipit orci.</p>
    </div>
    
    <div class="section-content production">
        <h2>TESTIMONIALS NOW</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec neque justo, consequat non fermentum ac, tempor eu turpis. Proin nulla eros, placerat non ipsum ut, dapibus ullamcorper ex. Nulla in dapibus lorem. Suspendisse vitae velit ac ante consequat placerat ut sed eros. Nullam porttitor mattis mi, id fringilla ex consequat eu. Praesent pulvinar tincidunt leo et condimentum. Maecenas volutpat turpis at felis egestas malesuada. Phasellus sem odio, venenatis at ex a, lacinia suscipit orci.</p>
    </div>
    
    <div class="section-content analysis">
        <h2>OUR LOCATIONS</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec neque justo, consequat non fermentum ac, tempor eu turpis. Proin nulla eros, placerat non ipsum ut, dapibus ullamcorper ex. Nulla in dapibus lorem. Suspendisse vitae velit ac ante consequat placerat ut sed eros. Nullam porttitor mattis mi, id fringilla ex consequat eu. Praesent pulvinar tincidunt leo et condimentum. Maecenas volutpat turpis at felis egestas malesuada. Phasellus sem odio, venenatis at ex a, lacinia suscipit orci.</p>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What do you mean by: `...not able to repeat the functions` ? Looks like the example runs from bubble to bubble, unless I'm missing something.

Comment: I want to iterate the click function like once it clicks the last step process then start from beginning..

Answer (score 0):

Need to reset `current` when the value exceeds the `inputs` array length:

```
// If current exceeds the inputs, then restart to 0.
if ( current > inputs.length - 1) {
    current = 0;
}
```

... to make it restart to the beginning.
(the code snippet above added after `current++;`, that's the only change)

Run the example below to see how it runs.

```js
 
    $(".step").click( function() {
    $(this).addClass("active").prevAll().addClass("active");
    $(this).nextAll().removeClass("active");    
});

$(".step01").click( function() {
    $("#line-progress").css("width", "3%");
    $(".discovery").addClass("active").siblings().removeClass("active");

});

$(".step02").click( function() {
    $("#line-progress").css("width", "25%");
    $(".strategy").addClass("active").siblings().removeClass("active");
});

$(".step03").click( function() {
    $("#line-progress").css("width", "50%");
    $(".creative").addClass("active").siblings().removeClass("active");
});

$(".step04").click( function() {
    $("#line-progress").css("width", "75%");
    $(".production").addClass("active").siblings().removeClass("active");
});

$(".step05").click( function() {
    $("#line-progress").css("width", "100%");
    $(".analysis").addClass("active").siblings().removeClass("active");
});

(function() {
    var inputs = document.getElementsByClassName('step'),
        current = 0,
        timer = window.setInterval(
            function () {
                var input = inputs[current];
                if (input) {
                    input.click();
                    current++;

                    // If current exceeds the inputs, then restart to 0.
                    if ( current > inputs.length - 1) {
                        current = 0;
                    }
                } else {
                    window.clearInterval(timer);
                }
            }
        ,3000);

}());
```

```css
.process-wrapper {
    margin:auto;
    max-width:1080px;
}

#progress-bar-container {
    position:relative;
    width:90%;
    margin:auto;
    height:100px;
    margin-top:65px;
}

#progress-bar-container ul {
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    padding-top:15px;
    z-index:9999;
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    margin-top:-40px
}

#progress-bar-container li:before {
    content:" ";
    display:block;
    margin:auto;
    width:30px;
    height:30px;
    border-radius:50%;
    border:solid 2px #aaa;
    transition:all ease 0.3s;
     
}

#progress-bar-container li.active:before, #progress-bar-container li:hover:before {
    border:solid 2px #fff;
         
    background: linear-gradient(to right, #E91E63 0%,#fff 100%); 
}

#progress-bar-container li {
    list-style:none;
    float:left;
    width:20%;
    text-align:center;
    color:#aaa;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    font-size:11px;
    cursor:pointer;
    font-weight:700;
    transition:all ease 0.2s;
    vertical-align:bottom;
    height:60px;
    position:relative;
}

#progress-bar-container li .step-inner {
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    bottom:0;
    font-size: 14px;
}

#progress-bar-container li.active, #progress-bar-container li:hover {
    color:#444;
}

#progress-bar-container li:after {
    content:" ";
    display:block;
    width:6px;
    height:6px;
    background:#777;
    margin:auto;
    border:solid 7px #fff;
    border-radius:50%;
    margin-top:40px;
    box-shadow:0 2px 13px -1px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    transition:all ease 0.2s;
     
}

#progress-bar-container li:hover:after {
    background:#555;
}

#progress-bar-container li.active:after {
    background:#207893;
}

#progress-bar-container #line {
    width:80%;
    margin:auto;
    background: #eee;
    height:6px;
    position:absolute;
    left:10%;
    top:57px;
    z-index:1;
    border-radius:50px;
    transition:all ease 0.9s;
}

#progress-bar-container #line-progress {
    content:" ";
    width:3%;
    height:100%;
    background: #207893;     
    background: linear-gradient(to right, #207893 0%,#2ea3b7 100%); 
    position:absolute;
    z-index:2;
    border-radius:50px;
    transition:all ease 0.9s;
}

#progress-content-section {
    width:90%;
    margin: auto;
    background: #f3f3f3;
    border-radius: 4px;
}

#progress-content-section .section-content {
    padding:30px 40px;
    text-align:center;
}

#progress-content-section .section-content h2 {
    font-size:17px;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    color:#333;
    letter-spacing:1px;
}

#progress-content-section .section-content p {
    font-size:16px;
    line-height:1.8em;
    color:#777;
}

#progress-content-section .section-content {
    display:none;
    animation: FadeInUp 700ms ease 1;
    animation-fill-mode:forwards;
    transform:translateY(15px);
    opacity:0;
}

#progress-content-section .section-content.active {
    display:block;
}

@keyframes FadeInUp {
    0% {
        transform:translateY(15px);
        opacity:0;
    }
    
    100% {
        transform:translateY(0px);
        opacity:1;
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="process-wrapper">
<div id="progress-bar-container">
    <ul>
        <li class="step step01 active"><div class="step-inner">HOME WORK</div></li>
        <li class="step step02"><div class="step-inner">RESPONSIVE PART</div></li>
        <li class="step step03"><div class="step-inner">Creative cREATIONS</div></li>
        <li class="step step04"><div class="step-inner">TESTIMONIALS PART</div></li>
        <li class="step step05"><div class="step-inner">OUR LOCATIONS</div></li>        
    </ul>
    <div id="line">
        <div id="line-progress"></div>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="progress-content-section">
    <div class="section-content discovery active">
        <h2>HOME SECTION</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec neque justo, consequat non fermentum ac, tempor eu turpis. Proin nulla eros, placerat non ipsum ut, dapibus ullamcorper ex. Nulla in dapibus lorem. Suspendisse vitae velit ac ante consequat placerat ut sed eros. Nullam porttitor mattis mi, id fringilla ex consequat eu. Praesent pulvinar tincidunt leo et condimentum. Maecenas volutpat turpis at felis egestas malesuada. Phasellus sem odio, venenatis at ex a, lacinia suscipit orci.</p>
    </div>
    
    <div class="section-content strategy">
        <h2>GALLERY SECTION</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec neque justo, consequat non fermentum ac, tempor eu turpis. Proin nulla eros, placerat non ipsum ut, dapibus ullamcorper ex. Nulla in dapibus lorem. Suspendisse vitae velit ac ante consequat placerat ut sed eros. Nullam porttitor mattis mi, id fringilla ex consequat eu. Praesent pulvinar tincidunt leo et condimentum. Maecenas volutpat turpis at felis egestas malesuada. Phasellus sem odio, venenatis at ex a, lacinia suscipit orci.</p>
    </div>
    
    <div class="section-content creative">
        <h2>Creative CREATIONS</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec neque justo, consequat non fermentum ac, tempor eu turpis. Proin nulla eros, placerat non ipsum ut, dapibus ullamcorper ex. Nulla in dapibus lorem. Suspendisse vitae velit ac ante consequat placerat ut sed eros. Nullam porttitor mattis mi, id fringilla ex consequat eu. Praesent pulvinar tincidunt leo et condimentum. Maecenas volutpat turpis at felis egestas malesuada. Phasellus sem odio, venenatis at ex a, lacinia suscipit orci.</p>
    </div>
    
    <div class="section-content production">
        <h2>TESTIMONIALS NOW</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec neque justo, consequat non fermentum ac, tempor eu turpis. Proin nulla eros, placerat non ipsum ut, dapibus ullamcorper ex. Nulla in dapibus lorem. Suspendisse vitae velit ac ante consequat placerat ut sed eros. Nullam porttitor mattis mi, id fringilla ex consequat eu. Praesent pulvinar tincidunt leo et condimentum. Maecenas volutpat turpis at felis egestas malesuada. Phasellus sem odio, venenatis at ex a, lacinia suscipit orci.</p>
    </div>
    
    <div class="section-content analysis">
        <h2>OUR LOCATIONS</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec neque justo, consequat non fermentum ac, tempor eu turpis. Proin nulla eros, placerat non ipsum ut, dapibus ullamcorper ex. Nulla in dapibus lorem. Suspendisse vitae velit ac ante consequat placerat ut sed eros. Nullam porttitor mattis mi, id fringilla ex consequat eu. Praesent pulvinar tincidunt leo et condimentum. Maecenas volutpat turpis at felis egestas malesuada. Phasellus sem odio, venenatis at ex a, lacinia suscipit orci.</p>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Bingo...That's awesome.. Thank you Paul.